# Extracting zip file and then cd into it with different filename

Tags: linux, bash, tar

I am creating a bash script to extract a tar file and cd'ing into it and then it runs another script. So far this has been working pretty well with my code below, however, i ran into a case where if the extracted folder is different than the .tar file name then it would cause an issue. So my question is, how should I handle unique cases where the file name is different than then .tar filename.

e.g,) my_file.tar ---> after extraction ----> my_different_file_name

```
#!/bin/bash

fname=$1

echo the file you are about to extract is $fname

if [ -f $fname ]; then         #if the file exists
    tar -xvzf $fname       #tar it
    cd ${fname%.*}         #the `%.*` will extract filename from     filename.tgz and cd into it
    echo ${fname%.*}
    echo $PWD
    loadIt                 #another script to load
fi
```

Comment: Will your tarballs only ever create **one** toplevel directory? If so, and your starting directory is clean, then `cd *` would work (but isn't reliable if that isn't the case). Are there contents of the extracted tarballs you can use to find your target directory?

Comment: @EtanReisner No, there could be other directories that already exists in that same level, if i did `cd *` i believe it would cd into a different directory than the one that was just extracted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do a:

```
 topDir=$(tar -xvzf $fname | sed "s|/.*$||" | uniq)
 [ $(wc -w <<< $topDir) == 1 ] || exit 1
 echo topDir=$topDir
```

Explanation: the first command untars vebosely (outputs all files it's untarring), and then gets all the leading directory names, and pipes them into uniq.  (so basically it returns a list of all the top level directories in the tar file).   The next line checks that there's exactly one entry in topDir, otherwise it exits.
At this point $topdir will be the directory you want to cd into.

Comment: When I tried that it gives me `[ 0 == 1 ]` on the second line.

Comment: @kkmoslehpour Did you use `-v` with tar? `0` for the `wc` output means there wasn't any contents.

Comment: @John Yes I tried the exact code you have above but was giving me 0 for wc

Comment: That could be a couple of things: 1) the tar file is in fact empty (try running `tar -tf tarfile.tar.gz` to confirm, 2) `$fname` was not populated properly (either it's empty or points to a non-existant tar file, or it points to a tar file that's not created with gzip).   This would cause tar to spit out a message to stderr.   3) the tar file only contains files (no subdirectories).  You can try to manually run `tar -xvzf tarfile.tar.gz` on the command line to see what you get.

Comment: @John This worked, however, could you explain the sed command you did there I don't quite get what it's doing there. Also this would only work for tgz files, if the file was a .zip this wouldnt work, is there a way to do the same thing for zip files?

Comment: The sed command uses the `s/regexp/replacement/` command.   Note that I used `|` instead of `/` as the delimiter as I personally find that easier to read (you can use any character as a delimiter).   The regexp is `/.*$`.   This means it searches for the first slash ( \\ ), then matches any character (`.`) repeated zero or more times (`*`) until it hits the end of input `$`.   It then replaces this with replacement, which is blank in this case.   So in other words, it finds the first \\ and wipes it and everything following it out, leaving you with just the top directory name.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could do something like that:

```
cd $(tar -tf $fname | head -1)
```

Comment: There's no guarantee that the first entry is the top level directory -- some tar files don't store directory names at all.

Comment: Ack. I've assumed every tar file would have one and only one top level folder. But if this can't be guaranteed in this specific case, maybe it would be better to use "find" to make sure "loadIt" exists and find its correct location.

Comment: @Fredi Hi this solution could actually work, however, let's say instead of a tar, it is a zip or any other compressed file, is there a way to handle this?

Comment: Again, this will not work, as tar does not guarantee that the top level directory will be the first entry in the tar file.  Depending on how the tar file was created (which version of tar was used, how many times it was run, etc), you could get varying results.  Assuming this would make your code prone to error.    If you wanted to assume that everything in the folder is in a single directory, then you could use sed to strip everything after the first / in the first entry of the tar file.  This would be safer.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind moving the directory around after you extract it you can do something like this

```
# Create a temporary directory
$ tmpd=$(mktemp -d)
# Change to the temporary directory
$ pushd "$tmpd"
# Extract the tarball
$ tar -xf "$fname"
# Glob the directory name
$ d=(*)
# Error if we have more (or less) than one directory
$ [ "${#d}" = 0 ] || exit 1
# Explicitly use just the first directory (optional since `$d` does the same thing)
$ d=${d[0]}
# Move the extracted directory to the previous directory
$ mv "$d" "$OLDPWD"
# Change back to the starting directory
$ popd
# Remove the (now empty) temporary directory
$ rmdir "$tmpd"
# Change into the extracted directory
$ cd "$d"
# Run 'loadIt'
$ loadIt
```